# Shrink div as window shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have 2 horizontal divs next to each. I all trying to get the div on the right to shrink down as the window is made made smaller but it drops to the next line. Also I want the div on the right to reach the outer border of its container div.

The only success i have is if a put a percentage width on the right div but then it does touch the container border.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdJBP/3/)

Here is the code
HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="rsfeed">
                            <div class="rsfeedlabel">RSS Stream</div>
                            <div class="rsfeedinfo ofh">
                                <table class="rsfeedtbl">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>otam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab - Illo inventore veritatis et quasi rem aperiam, eaque ipsa inventore veritatis et quasi rem </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 90%;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
}

#rsfeed {font-family: Arial;position: relative;overflow: hidden;}

#rsfeed .rsfeedlabel {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #727272;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: grey;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color:  white;
    font-family: Arial;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    font-size: 75%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;

}

#rsfeed .rsfeedinfo {
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-right: 1px solid #b9b8b8; border-top: 1px solid #b9b8b8; border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b8b8;
    margin-top: 20px; 
    font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Arial;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*width:80%;*/
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now **remove** `float left` of this **class**

```
#rsfeed .rsfeedinfo
```

**and** `add white-space nowrap` in your **id** `#rsfeed`
**As like this**

```
    #rsfeed .rsfeedinfo {
    float:left;  // remove this line
    }

#rsfeed {
white-space:nowrap; //add this line
}
```

**Live demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/MdJBP/4/